# Проверка на запись

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите как добавить проверку в код

```
$content = file_get_contents("lp.php");
$content = str_replace('$aa = ""', '$aa = "con-23"', $content);
file_put_contents("lp.php", $content);
```

В чём нужна проверка что бы он только записывал 0-9 и a-z, он у меня заносит в файл как con-23 а мне нужно что бы без "-" просто con23, Кто помочь сможет ?!

Comment: Смотрите 
$content = str_replace('$aa = ""', '$aa = "con-23"', $content);
Я вписал con-23 а он мне должен записать в файл lp.php без знака "-", То есть должен записать con23, Пример
Я вставляю 23-45-67 он мне записывает 234567

Answer (score 2):

**Упрощенный вариант**

```
$raw = 'con-23'; //сюда пишешь то, что фильтровать хочешь
$value = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/u', '', $raw);

$content = file_get_contents("lp.php");
$content = str_replace('$aa = ""', '$aa = "' . $value . '"', $content);
file_put_contents("lp.php", $content);
```

**Вариант посложнее:**

```
$prefix = '$aa = "'; //Все, что до фильтруемого значения
$suffix = '"'; //Все, что после фильтруемого значения

$raw_body_replacement = 'con-23'; //что фильтруем
$body_replacement = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/u', '', $raw_body_replacement);
$body_search = '';

$search = $prefix . $body_search . $suffix;
$replacement = $prefix . $body_replacement . $suffix;

$content = file_get_contents("lp.php");
$content = str_replace($search, $replacement, $content);
file_put_contents("lp.php", $content);
```

Comment: Твой код работает но он мне занёт вот так
aacon23 а раньше заносил так, aa = ""

Comment: Исправил свой ответ

Comment: $suffix = '"'; //Все, что после фильтруемого значения - что сюда ?!

Comment: Мне надо просто что бы я вставил допустим con-23 а он в файле записал вот так
$aa = "con23"

Comment: @svoloch196, Так фильтруйте текст который вставляете через preg_replace (как мы показываем), и вставляйте  в файл "$aa =" + результат из фильтра

Comment: Я не понял ))) можешь сразу заполнить что бы было $aa = ""

Comment: **Переменные**  
$prefix || $body_replacement || $suffix;  
**Значения**  
$aa = " || 'con-23' || "  
Теперь понятнее? Для конкретно вашего примера с 'con-23' ничего менять не надо.

Comment: @svoloch196 , добавил в решения вариант попроще...

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
$content = 'con-23'; //то, что вы хотите отфильтровать.

$filedata = file_get_contents("lp.php"); //получаем данные из файла

$empty=""; //пустая область (для того, что бы заменить не нужные знаки)

$result = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/U",$empty,$content);  // заменяем все не нужные знаки на пустое место (оставляем только латинские буквы, от a до z (в нижнем регистре) и цифры, от 0 до 9)
```

Записываем наши отфильтрованные данные в фал "***lp.php***". Сначала ***$filedata*** потом "***$aa =*** ", а после и наш отфильтрованный **$result**:

```
file_put_contents("lp.php", $filedata."$aa = ".$result);
```

Comment: Ключ /i не нужен. @svoloch196 указывал только маленькие буквы.

Comment: @VenZell, Ок) Подправил )

Comment: @svoloch196, Обновил. Разжевал.